# Eclipse not copying resource files to target directory

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I've been having a weird problem with eclipse.

When I compile my project via terminal with maven, it copies all the config files that I have inside my resources to the target dir, as expected.
But when I try to execute my JUnit tests inside Eclipse, it compiles the project again, but this time, doesn't copy the files to the designated target dir.
I tried running `mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse` on my project, to see if it helps and configures the project inside the IDE in a proper way, but still have the same behavior.

Does anyone had this behavior before? I couldn't find something related, so far.

Comment: do not use `eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse` anymore the plugin is retired a long time ago... use the import function of Eclipse ...

Comment: @khmarbaise, importing the project as a maven project or creating it with mvn eclipse:eclipse gives me the same behavior. Eclipse is still not copying the resource files to the target dir, while via terminal they get copied.

Comment: So not use eclipse:.. as I wrote retired a long time and could fail to write correct information because eclipse has changed in the mean time... Furthermore which verison of Eclipse do you use?

Comment: @khmarbaise, I'm using Version: 2020-06 (4.16.0), Build id: 20200615-1200

Comment: Please show the pom file or a link to the project...